# finding the difference of the sum of a column values based on an indicator(a/b) column in a table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
select ca.cust_ac_no, ca.ccy, ah.trn_dt,
(SELECT  sum(COALESCE(hi.lcy_amount,0))                                    
     FROM actb_history hi 
     WHERE hi.ac_no='0013001600038'  and hi.drcr_ind = 'C' and ah.trn_dt = hi.trn_dt
     GROUP BY hi.ac_no,hi.drcr_ind) as Total_Credits,
(SELECT  sum(COALESCE(hi.lcy_amount,0))                                    
     FROM actb_history hi 
     WHERE hi.ac_no='0013001600038'  and hi.drcr_ind = 'D'and ah.trn_dt = hi.trn_dt
     GROUP BY hi.ac_no,hi.drcr_ind) as Total_Debits,

((SELECT  sum( COALESCE(hi.lcy_amount,0))                                    
     FROM actb_history hi 
     WHERE hi.ac_no='0013001600038'  and hi.drcr_ind = 'C' and ah.trn_dt = hi.trn_dt
     GROUP BY hi.ac_no,hi.drcr_ind)
     -
(SELECT  sum(COALESCE(hi.lcy_amount,0))                                    
     FROM actb_history hi 
     WHERE hi.ac_no='0013001600038'  and hi.drcr_ind = 'D'and ah.trn_dt = hi.trn_dt
     GROUP BY hi.drcr_ind,hi.drcr_ind )) as difference

from actb_history ah, sttm_cust_account ca
where ah.ac_no='0013001600038'
and ah.ac_no = ca.cust_ac_no
group by ca.cust_ac_no,  ca.ccy, ah.trn_dt
```

The Above code calculates the difference only where there are corresponding values for total_credits and total_debits

The formula is credit-debit= difference. The problem is some transactions have only one and the other is null. so the result is null after adding the nulls.

My desire is that it should display zero for any null value and be able to carry out the subtraction.

Please help.

Comment: Is there anything in `actb_history` other than `'C'` and `'D'` transactions?

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like a much simpler query would fit the bill:

```
select ca.cust_ac_no, ca.ccy, ah.trn_dt,
      SUM(CASE WHEN ah.drcr_ind='C' THEN ah.lcy_amount ELSE 0 END) as Total_Credits,
      SUM(CASE WHEN ah.drcr_ind='D' THEN ah.lcy_amount ELSE 0 END) as Total_Debts,
      SUM(CASE WHEN ah.drcr_ind='C' THEN ah.lcy_amount ELSE 0 END)-
      SUM(CASE WHEN ah.drcr_ind='D' THEN ah.lcy_amount ELSE 0 END) as Different
from
   actb_history ah
      inner join
   sttm_cust_account ca
      on
         ah.ac_no = ca.cust_ac_no
where ah.ac_no='0013001600038'
group by ca.cust_ac_no,  ca.ccy, ah.trn_dt
```

Comment: +1 - This is exactly the query I was writing. It gets rid of the unnecesary subquerys and use a proper join.

Comment: You might still want coalesce(sum(...),0) in there.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - If there is even a *single* row (which there must be for the join to occur), then it's all `1`s and `0`s, no `NULL`s in sight.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but if there is no 'D' or no 'C' and the other exists then you gots a problem

Answer (score 2):

For the minimum change to your code, you need to move where you have the `COALESCE()` statements.

Instead of inside the sub-queries, move them outside of the sub-queries.

```
select ca.cust_ac_no, ca.ccy, ah.trn_dt,
(SELECT  sum(COALESCE(hi.lcy_amount,0))                                    
     FROM actb_history hi 
     WHERE hi.ac_no='0013001600038'  and hi.drcr_ind = 'C' and ah.trn_dt = hi.trn_dt
     GROUP BY hi.ac_no,hi.drcr_ind) as Total_Credits,
(SELECT  sum(COALESCE(hi.lcy_amount,0))                                    
     FROM actb_history hi 
     WHERE hi.ac_no='0013001600038'  and hi.drcr_ind = 'D'and ah.trn_dt = hi.trn_dt
     GROUP BY hi.ac_no,hi.drcr_ind) as Total_Debits,

COALESCE((SELECT  sum(hi.lcy_amount)                                    
     FROM actb_history hi 
     WHERE hi.ac_no='0013001600038'  and hi.drcr_ind = 'C' and ah.trn_dt = hi.trn_dt
     GROUP BY hi.ac_no,hi.drcr_ind), 0)
     -
COALESCE((SELECT  sum(hi.lcy_amount)                                    
     FROM actb_history hi 
     WHERE hi.ac_no='0013001600038'  and hi.drcr_ind = 'D'and ah.trn_dt = hi.trn_dt
     GROUP BY hi.drcr_ind,hi.drcr_ind ), 0) as difference

from actb_history ah, sttm_cust_account ca
where ah.ac_no='0013001600038'
and ah.ac_no = ca.cust_ac_no
group by ca.cust_ac_no,  ca.ccy, ah.trn_dt
```

This is because it is possible for there to be no records being `SUM()`ed by the correlated sub-queries.  Where that's the case, you don't have `SUM(0)`, you have nothing at all (`NULL`).  Putting the `COALESCE()` outside the sub-query, therefore, turns the `no records processed` into a `0`.

Comment: thanks alot, it worked out. I can feel the burden off my shoulder now. wheeeew. Thank you

Comment: You could also wrap the Sum() in the Coalesce() instead of the other way round. A query that returns only aggregate functions will always return a single row even if there are no matching records. It might be easier to read as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try making `COALESCE` of the `SUM`.